# How do I get the id of checked checkboxes from recyclerview in android studio?

Tags: android, checkbox

I have a recyclearview with A few checkboxes. text and id of checkboxes received from the API. I should send id of checked checkboxes to API. now, I have two problems:

- how to get checked checkboxes ids and store in a String value? this
  the string must be used in the activity.
- when a user clicks to checkbox and this checked, id of checkbox save
  in String. now, User regrets and unchecked checkbox. in String, the id of checkbox should remove.

One of my solutions is :

- create a data model(Info_Checkbox) that contain method get and set
  ID.
- create ArrayList.
- set checked checkboxes id to this array list and use this array to
  send params to server.

But my code is incorrect! when I checked a number of checkboxes, array list save the last checkboxes id. can you help me?

```
Context context;
public ArrayList<Info_Filter> items = new ArrayList<>();
public SparseBooleanArray array = new SparseBooleanArray();
public List<Info_Filter> orig;
public ArrayList<Info_Checkbox> checkboxes = new ArrayList<>();
private Info_Checkbox info_checkbox = new Info_Checkbox();
public AdapterRecyFilterGroup(Context context, ArrayList<Info_Filter> items) {
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
}
@NonNull
@Override
public SetViewHolderFilter onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.sample_filter_grouping, viewGroup, false);
    return new SetViewHolderFilter(view);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SetViewHolderFilter setViewHolderFilter, int i) {
    setViewHolderFilter.checkBox.setText(items.get(i).getName());
    if (array.get(i)) {
        setViewHolderFilter.checkBox.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        setViewHolderFilter.checkBox.setChecked(false);
    }
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items == null ? 0 : items.size();
}

public class SetViewHolderFilter extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    CheckBox checkBox;
    public SetViewHolderFilter(@NonNull final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        checkBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cb_filter);
        checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (array.get(getAdapterPosition())) {      //!checked
                    array.put(getAdapterPosition(), false);
                    info_checkbox.setId(items.get(getAdapterPosition()).getId());
                    checkboxes.remove(info_checkbox);
                } else {        //checked
                    array.put(getAdapterPosition(), true);
                    info_checkbox.setId(items.get(getAdapterPosition()).getId());
                    checkboxes.add(info_checkbox);
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and in Activity:

```
private String getCheckboxes(ArrayList<Info_Checkbox> checkboxes) {

    String category = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < checkboxes.size(); i++) {
        category = checkboxes.get(i).getId() + "," + category;
    }
    Log.i("asfaf", category);
    checkboxes.clear();
    return category;
}
```

if id of checked checkboxes are {7,5}, this method returned {5,5}.

Comment: Why don't you use the boolean value for that

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: @NigamPatro post updated.

Comment: @sajjadjavadi Please check the answer I have added.

Answer (score 1):

You need to maintain one selected item list in your adapter. and just add and remove the item from that list onCheckedChanged listener. and after a click on submit or wherever you want you can take that list from your adapter and just map that list and get only string list which will be your selected IDs list. and you can join that in a single string by a comma separated. for joining the list ids to string you can you.

`TextUtils.join(",",[Your IDs list])`

Comment: look at my code. I have an array list. where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

Here, you have created only one instance of `info_checkbox`, and every time you are adding the same instance to the list. Here it is creating an issue. For every item position, you have to create an instance of the class and add it to list or remove from the list.

**Solution 2**

You can traverse the `SparseBooleanArray` object and get the item from the list based on the position from your data and create the required data.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is recording CheckBox's id, while the CheckBox is re-used by the RecyclerView, i.e., the same CheckBox is used for item 1, and when item 1 scrolls off the screen and item 7 enters the screen, same CheckBox binds to item 7.

So if you check item 1 and then scroll and check item 7, in your checkboxes, you got same id twice.

Looking at your code, these codes are not necessary:

```
public ArrayList<Info_Checkbox> checkboxes = new ArrayList<>();
private Info_Checkbox info_checkbox = new Info_Checkbox();

                info_checkbox.setId(items.get(getAdapterPosition()).getId());
                checkboxes.remove(info_checkbox);

                info_checkbox.setId(items.get(getAdapterPosition()).getId());
                checkboxes.add(info_checkbox);
```

You can get checked item's indexes from array, which records which items are checked (check true items in the array):

```
public SparseBooleanArray array = new SparseBooleanArray();
```

This will give you complete checked items:

```
private String getCheckedItems() {

    String category = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        if (array.get(i, false))
            category = category + String.valueOf(i) + ",";
    }
    Log.i("asfaf", category);
    return category;
}
```